# Downcasting Core Data error

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am using Core data, and in my `AppDelegate.swift`, I get the following error on this line `dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError`:

> 'ErrorType' is not convertible to 'NSError'; did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?

Here is the corresponding code:

```
lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and returns a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    // Create the coordinator and store
    let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("On The Go.sqlite")
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    do {
        try coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil)
    } catch {
        // Report any error we got.
        var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason

        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError
        let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }

    return coordinator
}()
```

Here is the screenshot of the code:

[image]

I did what the error suggested, but the same error existed.

Comment: What version of Xcode do you use ? This code compiles for me...

Comment: I use Xcode 7.2.1 @Whirlwind

Comment: btw--you could probably use a dictionary literal (`dict = [key:value, ...]`) in your catch block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you change your catch to include a pattern match on NSError errors?

```
do {
} catch let e as NSError {
    // handle NSError case
} catch {
}
```

Since your block can now throw, you will have to change your function like this:

```
lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = try? { () throws in
    // your code
}
```

Comment: When I do this, the error goes, but I get the error "Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled." This is on the first line of the function I posted in my question.

Comment: I think you will need to add a type declaration to your block:

Comment: How would I go about this, sorry I don't understand.

Comment: I don't think the block can throw, as the error is already handled.

Comment: Yes, I tried what you added to the answer, but it didn't work. cc @TimVermeulen

Comment: You need to add a _try?_ before your block since it can throw. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `catch` with `catch let error as NSError`.

Comment: When I do this, the error goes, but I get the error "Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled." This is on the first line of the function I posted in my question.

Comment: On the first line I posted in my function.

Comment: What do you suggest?

Comment: Your code works fine on my Mac, so I'm a bit clueless. Could you maybe upload a screenshot of your code including the error?

Comment: I've added the screenshot.

Comment: The answer by @nielsbot fixed my challenge. Thanks for contributing.

Comment: @SWFApp Okay, but I'm a bit confused as you're both handling an error and letting the function throw, which means that you'll have to handle the error again when you use that variable...